# Angular - ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: angular

In my Angular-12 project I have this code that will register users and also insert image into the directory and DB using Laravel-8 api:

Interface:

```
export interface ICompanySetup {
  companyName: string;
  registrationNumber: string;
  dateEstablished: Date;
  company_logo: any;
 }
```

service:

```
createCompanySignup(data: any): Observable<ICompanySetup[]> {
  return this.http.post<ICompanySetup[]>(this.api.baseURL + 'signup', data, this.httpOption);
}
```

component:

```js
import {
  ApiService
} from 'src/app/services/api.service';

export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  isLinear = true;
  isLoading = false;
  companySetupForm!: FormGroup;
  companyForm!: FormGroup;
  idForm!: FormGroup;
  imageSrcLogo!: string | ArrayBuffer;
  files: any;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private api: ApiService,
    private route: Router,
  ) {}

  onFileChange(event: any) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
      const [file] = event.target.files;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);

      reader.onload = () => {
        this.imageSrcLogo = reader.result as string;

        this.companyInfoForm.get('company_logo') ? .setValue(file);
      };

    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.companyForm = this.fb.group({
      companyName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(100)]],
      dateEstablished: ['', [Validators.required]],
      company_logo: ['', [
        RxwebValidators.extension({
          extensions: ["jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "png", "gif", "svg"]
        })
      ]],
    }, {
      updateOn: "blur"
    });
    this.idForm = this.fb.group({
      registrationNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)]],
    });
  }

  get fc() {
    return this.companyForm.controls;
  };
  get fi() {
    return this.idForm.controls;
  };

  onSubmit() {
    this.isSubmitted = true;

    const formCompanyData = this.companyForm.getRawValue();
    const formIdData = this.idForm.getRawValue();

    const formData = new FormData();
    var datestr = (new Date(formCompanyData.dateEstablished)).toUTCString();
    formData.append('companyName', formCompanyData.companyName);
    formData.append("company_logo", this.files, this.files.name);
    formData.append('registrationNumber', formCompanyData.registrationNumber);
    formData.append("dateEstablished", datestr);

    this.spinnerService.show();
    const header = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };

    this.isLoading = true;
    this.companyService.createCompanySignup(formData).subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.router.navigate(['admin/category']).then(() => this.showToasterSuccess(res.message));
      },
      error => this.router.navigate(['admin/category']).then(() => this.showToasterError(error[0].message))
    );;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper labelPosition="bottom">
  <mat-step [stepControl]="companyForm">
    <form [formGroup]="companyForm">
      <ng-template matStepLabel matStepperIcon="phone">Company Info</ng-template>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
          <div class="card-body box-profile">
            <div class="text-center">
              <img class="profile-user-img img-fluid img-circle" [src]="imageSrcLogo || 'assets/img/no-image.png'" alt="No Company Logo" style="height:150px; width:150px">
            </div>

            <h3 class="profile-username text-center">Company Logo</h3>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="file"></label>
              <input formControlName="company_logo" id="file" type="file" class="form-control" (change)="onFileChange($event)">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dateEstablished">Date Registered:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
          <mat-form-field fxFlex="100%" fxFlex.gt-sm>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dateEstablished" placeholder="Choose a date" [max]="tomorrow" formControlName="dateEstablished" readonly required>
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateEstablished"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #dateEstablished></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="fc.dateEstablished.touched && fc.dateEstablished.invalid">
          <div *ngIf="fc.dateEstablished.hasError('required')">
            <div class="text-danger">
              Date Registered is required!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Company Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>}
          <input type="text" formControlName="companyName" placeholder="Company Name" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="fc.companyName.touched && fc.companyName.invalid">
          <div *ngIf="fc.companyName.hasError('required')">
            <div class="text-danger">
              Company Name is required!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="fc.companyName.hasError('minlength')">
            <div class="text-danger">
              Company Name cannot be less than 3 characters!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="fc.companyName.hasError('maxlength')">
            <div class="text-danger">
              Company Name cannot be more than 100 characters!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext [disabled]="companyForm.status != 'VALID'">Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="idForm">
    <form [formGroup]="idForm">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Company ID</ng-template>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="registration_number">Registration Number:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" formControlName="registrationNumber" placeholder="Registration Number" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="fi.registrationNumber.touched && fi.registrationNumber.invalid">
          <div *ngIf="fi.registrationNumber.hasError('required')">
            <div class="text-danger">
              Company Reg. No. is required!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="fi.registrationNumber.hasError('maxlength')">
            <div class="text-danger">
              Company Reg. No. cannot be more than 100 characters!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <button mat-raised-button color="black" matStepperPrevious>Back</button> &nbsp;
        <button mat-raised-button color="success" [disabled]="isLoading" type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">
                            <span *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
                              Submit
                          </button> &nbsp;
        <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
      </div>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

this.files.name  is the name for company_logo on change.

When I submitted the form, I got these two (2) errors:

> 1. core.js:6456 ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.

> 2. ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

and it points at:

> formData.append("company_logo", this.files, this.files.name);

I am trying to signup a user with logo upload.  I've been on this for a long time without any solution.

How do I get this sorted out?

Or is there any better way of doing it?

Especially the first error.

Thanks